# Random Position Multiple Images

Tags: jquery

I am using this simple script that will randomly place an image with the class `.random` on the page -- works great. Trying to figure out a way to apply this to multiple images on the page using a single class, so that the images are scattered over the page -- right now if it is applied to more than one image they all use the same random positioning.

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {
          var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth
          var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
          var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random()*bodyWidth));
          var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random()*bodyHeight));

          $('.random').css('left', randPosX);
          $('.random').css('top', randPosY);

        });
```

Comment: if you use the selector `$('.random')` it will apply to all images with such class (i.e. all of your images) - probably you want to loop through the list and apply the positions to each one individually

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth
  var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;

  $('.random').each(function(idx, img) {
    var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyWidth));
    var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHeight));
    console.log(randPosY);
    $(img).css('left', randPosX);
    $(img).css('top', randPosY);

  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 500px;
}
.random {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<img class="random" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
<img class="random" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
<img class="random" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
<img class="random" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
<img class="random" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
```

Comment: Thanks!  Cool solution, similar to the one above, also works great.

Comment: @adamo glad we could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery `each` to iterate through your selector matches. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth
    var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    $('.random').each(function() {
        var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyWidth));
        var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHeight));
        $(this).css('left', randPosX);
        $(this).css('top', randPosY);
        posLog.innerHTML = posXY
    });
});
```

Comment: if there are no other contents in the body, you may need to specify a height in the CSS (otherwise you will always get zero for the Y coord) - `body {
  height: 500px;
}`